# Is it possible to pass a string array as parameter using HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, high-order-component

I'm using some HOC components in my nextJS application to set some prop values via `getInitialProps`.
But I need to use dynamic values for these props.

In my index component I'm calling `withServerProps`. Is it possible to pass some string array to it?

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withTranslation } from 'i18n'
import withServerProps from 'with-server-props'

class Index extends Component {
  render () {
    return (<div>Some content</div>)
  }
}

export default withServerProps( // <-- How to pass an array with strings?
  withTranslation()(Index) 
)
```

I need to get the string array in this function:

**with-server-props.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default WrappedComponent =>
  class extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps (context) {
      const { query } = context
      return {
        id: query && query.id
        target: PASSED_ARRAY // <-- Need to recieve the array here
      }
    }
    render () {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you definitely can. Just add some arguments during the export in index.js.

```js
export default withServerProps(withTranslation()(Index), ["hello"])
```

Then in your HOC:

```js
export default function handleServerProps(WrappedComponent, arr) {
  class Hoc extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps (context) {
      const { query } = context
      return {
        id: query && query.id,
        target: arr,
      }
    }
    render () {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  return Hoc;
}
```

Comment: I do get the error `The default export is not a React Component`

Comment: Ah yes you need to return it in the function